# how will this expression will evaluate in C?

Tags: c, printf

I can't figure out how will this expression be evaluated in C?
I'm a bit confused with the evaluation of an expression inside printf?
If an expression inside printf evaluates from right to left then the evaluation of expression should've stopped after encountering (c>10), but it printed '1' to the output screen?

This is not exact syntax of C, but a question that was asked to me.

```
integer a = 50, b = 25, c = 0;
printf( a > 45 || b > 50 && c > 10 );
```

Comment: `a > 45 || b > 50 && c > 10` will grouped as `(a > 45 )|| (b > 50 && c > 10)`. Order of evaluation of sub-expressions will goes form left to right.

Comment: Also, check: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Please don;t write code like that, a couple of extra parenthesis won;t hurt anybody.

Comment: I forget to add that order of evaluation of operands of an operator is not  defined except for few like `||, &&` and `?:`. So, do not generalise the order mention in my first comment.

Comment: "If an expression inside printf evaluates from right to left..." Why would you even consider right-to-left evaluation as your first guess? Where did the idea of "right-to-left evaluation" come from?

Answer (score 2):

This expression

```
a > 45 || b > 50 && c > 10
```

is equivalent to expression

```
( a > 45 ) || ( b > 50 && c > 10 )
```

Thus if this subexpression `( a > 45 )` evaluates to true then the second subexpression will not evaluate and the result is equal 1 (of type int).

Otherwise this sub expression

```
( b > 50 && c > 10 )
```

is equivalent to

```
( b > 50 ) && ( c > 10 )
```

if `( b > 50 )` evaluates to false then the whole result is false (0 in C) and the second subexpression will not evaluate. Otherwise the result is the value of 
the subexpression `c > 10`. If `c > 10` then the result is an object of type int with value 1 or if not `( c > 10 )` then the value of the result is 0.

If the variables have values as it is shown in your question

```
int a = 50, b = 25, c = 0;
```

then the first subexpression

```
a > 45
```

evaluates to true and the result is 1 of type int. The second subexpression

```
b > 50 && c > 10
```

will not even evaluate.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f( int x )
{
    printf( "f is called for %d\n", x );
    return x;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int a = 50, b = 25, c = 0;

    f( f( a ) > 45 || f( b ) > 50 && f( c ) > 10 ); 

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
f is called for 50
f is called for 1
```

As you can see it was enough to calculate the expression `f( a ) > 45` to get the result equal to `1`.

Comment: You're awesome. This concept couldn't be explained more clearly than this. ThankYou for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

It would be undefined behaviour. The first argument to printf must be a format string. Most likely it will crash. What saves you is that "integer" is not a type, so it's not going to compile.

Comment: It's probably me who is responsible. I fixed formatting which makes this look like exact code but OP already mentioned _This is not exact syntax of C_ so I guess OP is aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Both the `||` and `&&` operators force left-to-right evaluation.  The left-hand operand will be fully evaluated (and all side effects applied) before the right-hand operand is evaluated.

Furthermore, both operators *short-circuit* - depending on the value of the left-hand operand, the right-hand operand may not be evaluated at all.

For

```
a || b
```

if `a` is true, then the *entire expression* is true regardless of the value of `b`, so `b` isn't evaluated.

Similarly, for

```
a && b
```

if `a` is false, then the *entire expression* is false regardless of the value of `b`, so `b` isn't evaluated.

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so

```
a || b && c
```

will be parsed as

```
a || (b && c)
```

and

```
a && b || c
```

will be parsed as

```
(a && b) || c
```

So...

```
a > 45 || b > 50 && c > 10
```

is parsed as

```
a > 45 || (b > 50 && c > 10 )
```

Since `a == 50`, `a > 45` is true.  Since `a > 45` is the left-hand operand of the `||` operator, the whole expression is true regardless of the right-hand operand, so `b > 50 && c > 10` isn't evaluated at all.

The result of expression is 1 (true).

Unfortunately, `printf` expects its first argument to point to a character string (the format string), and `1` is most likely not a valid address on your platform, so the result of this code will most likely be a segfault.  The easy fix would be to write

```
printf( "%d\n", a > 45 || b > 50 && c > 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The context in which an expression appears affects *whether* it is evaluated, but not *how*.  The order in which subexpressions of a larger expression are evaluated is controlled by [operator precedence and associativity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Among the operators in your expression, `>` has greatest precedence, then `&&`, then `||`.  All associate from left to right.  Therefore, your expression is evaluated exactly the same as if it were written like so:

```
(a > 45) || ((b > 50) && (c > 10))
```

Furthermore, the `&&` and `||` operators perform short-circuit evaluation.  This seems to be a point of confusion for you.  Short-circuit evaluation means that if the result of an `&&` or `||` operation is determined by the value of the left-hand operand, then the right-hand operand *of that operation* is not evaluated.  That does not affect whether or how *other* operations are evaluated, except to the extent that the result of the short-circuited operation is used as an operand.

In this case, however, because `||` associates left-to-right, `a > 45` is evaluated first, producing `1` (true).  Because this determines the result of the `||` operation, its right-hand operand is not evaluated.  Relative operator precedence yields the right-hand operand being the remainder of the overall expression, as shown above, so none of that will be evaluated.  Even if it *were* evaluated, however, the result of the overall expression would still be `1`, because the left-hand operand evaluates to `1`, regardless of the right-hand sub-expression.  That's why the right-hand side of the `||` does not need to be evaluated.